# Why there are a sequence of loss functions in DQN algorithm

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In section 2 of the paper Playing Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning, it says a Q-network can be trained by minimizing a sequence of loss functions. I do not understand why there is more than one loss function in this case.

[image: Loss functions for DQN]

Answer (score 0):

This sequence is really just a notation for iterative updates. It basically says, for the $i$th update, use your neural net parameters at timstep $i$ to make your prediction and use your neural net parameters from timestep $i-1$ to compute the target.